# MapKit in iOS 8 and Swift

Tags: ios, mapkit, swift, ios8

I'm trying to use MapKit on iOS 8 and I keep getting the error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call   
-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager 
requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

Looking it up here, I found that I had to implement `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` in my plist and also make a call to `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` but nothing happens and I still get that error in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` is the wrong key. Use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my application delegate I made an optional var for the locationManager outside the class and then set

```
locManager = CLLocationManager()
locManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

This causes the alert view to pop up with your NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription if you change it appropriately.

Then in the view controller file I made another var outside the class to hold a local CLLocationManager. I then set

```
if locManager {
        locMan = locManager!
        locMan!.delegate = self
    }
```

Then you can use the delegate method

```
func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager!,didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

which gets called when the authorisation status changes, which it does when the user responds to the pop up. Inside this you can use this bit of code to put the user location on the map

```
if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        map.showsUserLocation = true
    }
```

will add the users location to the map only if you are authorised for when in use.

Comment: That got rid of the error but it still doesn't request permission or show the user's location.

Comment: I think it only prompts you the first time you open the app so you either have to delete from the simulator or device or go into the settings and allow location

Comment: That didn't work and the app doesn't even show up under location settings.

Comment: In my AppDelegate.swift i have the following:  `import CoreLocation

var locManager: CLLocationManager?

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{
                            
 var window: UIWindow?
 

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  locManager = CLLocationManager()

  locManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  
  return true
 }`

Comment: And in the view controller:  `var locMan: CLLocationManager?
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate { 
 @IBOutlet var map : MKMapView
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  if locManager {
   locMan = locManager!
   locMan!.delegate = self
  }
 }
 func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: AnyObject[]!){
  self.map.showsUserLocation = true
 }`

Comment: and then the method that checks if the authorisation has changed in view controller: `func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager!,didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
 {
  if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
   map.showsUserLocation = true
  }
 }`

Comment: That didn't work in my project nor in a totally blank project. Not sure what's wrong...

Comment: @Phil could you provide a link to your (blank) project so that we can have a try and get a chance to fix it?

Comment: Hello guys, I found this repo with the other approach for locating the user and the output has the same error, I've being trying to have a working example for locating a user with MapKit for all week. Cheers, https://github.com/orlangur87/MapKit-Using

Comment: I was facing this problem,Now the popup is coming .But the problem is the popup disappears after 1/2 seconds.It does not take any input form user.Can you help me with this?I'm using objective c.

Comment: The key information is a variable outside the method focus. When I made a property, the alert box showed up. When the locationManager is created as a local variable inside a function, it is probably already deallocated when the alertBox is ready to show.

Answer (score 9):

I have been bothered by that one as well, until I realized that the `info.plist` key has changed. If you had `NSLocationUsageDescription` in, you will need to change to either `￼NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` (set at least one to `YES`), it is now mandatory in iOS8.

And then, Robert's code works, as it should (thanks for sharing).

Comment: Just a note: These keys aren't YES/NO.  You're supposed to put text that gives a reason that the user will see that explains why you need location (eg. "The app finds places of interest near you.").  So putting "YES" works but so will "NO" or "42" as long as some value is set for the key.

Answer (score 7):

It is NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, not NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription. Most places online have the wrong key

Comment: Thanks GOD! Spent a full day trying to figure out why nothing works and indeed it looks like many posts have got it wrong. thanks!!